# Explicit type PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, casting, plpgsql

I have a problem. There is a function, that counts total budget of department, including departments lower down the hierarchy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUBLIC.DEPT_BUDGET (DNO BPCHAR(3))
RETURNS TABLE (
    TOT DECIMAL(12,2)
)
AS $DEPT_BUDGET$
DECLARE sumb DECIMAL(12, 2);
DECLARE rdno BPCHAR(3)[];
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
DECLARE I BPCHAR(3);
BEGIN
    tot = 0;

    SELECT "BUDGET" FROM department WHERE dept_no = dno INTO tot;

    SELECT count("BUDGET") FROM department WHERE head_dept = dno INTO cnt;

    IF cnt = 0 
    THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT "BUDGET" FROM department WHERE dept_no = dno;
    END IF;
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(dept_no)
    FROM
        department
    WHERE
        head_dept = dno
    INTO
        rdno;
        
    FOREACH I IN ARRAY rdno
    LOOP
        SELECT * FROM DEPT_BUDGET(I) INTO SUMB;
        tot = tot + sumb;
    END LOOP;

END; $DEPT_BUDGET$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `dept_no` has `bpchar(3)` type. When I'm trying to call a function `SELECT public.dept_budget('000'::VARCHAR);` , I got an error:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function dept_budget(integer) does not exist. No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

When I change in-type parameter on `bpchar` or `char`, I got another error:

> SQL Error [22004]: ERROR: FOREACH expression must not be null.

I don't understand, why forced typization doesn't work. What should I do?
[Types of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGXzb.png)

UPD: Yeah, there is `bpchar`, but I have already tried to change everywhere `VARCHAR(3)` on `BPCHAR(3)`, and there is still an error.

Comment: try to replace  VARCHAR, char, bpchar to text data type. aslo count() function return bigint not int.

Comment: @jian unfortunately, Unfortunately, it didn't help. The result of foreach is still NULL.

Comment: To your question add:  1) What is the type `dept_no` in `department`? 2) Why `cast(dno as varchar)` when it is declared as argument `DNO VARCHAR(3)`? 3) What happens if you do `SELECT * FROM DEPT_BUDGET(I::varchar)`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) I add screenshot; 2) I thought, that postgres changes the type on some stage; 3) Still an error, that Foreach expression must not be null.

Comment: **DO NOT use screenshots**, copy and paste the information as text into the question.

Comment: 1) `bpchar` is just an alias for `char`, I would use `char` to be clearer. 2) Just before the `FOREACH I ...` I would add `RAISE NOTICE %, rdno;`. The error would seem to indicate there is no value for `rdno`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function could be written in sql instead of plpgsql. Try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUBLIC.DEPT_BUDGET (DNO VARCHAR)
RETURNS DECIMAL(12,2) LANGUAGE sql AS $$
    SELECT sum( CASE
                  WHEN dept_no = dno
                  THEN budget
                  ELSE dept_budget(dept_no)
                END
              ) :: decimal(12,2)
      FROM department 
     WHERE dept_no = dno
        OR head_dept = dno ;
$$ ;
```